# How to set an environment variable, usable in another session, but being lost at restart

Tags: windows, environment-variables

## Background

In my company, the result of the `DATE /T` is used as an input for a script, launched via another virtual machine (`RunProgramInGuest ...`).

We are today beginning of May, and I'd like to pretend that we are still April.

At this moment, I'm modifying the system clock for this, but I'd like to use another approach, by setting environment variable DATE, but I'd like following lifecycle:

### What do I need

- As the mentioned script is launched from outside my computer, this new environment variable should be usable from that new process too, so the environment variable should be somehow persistent.
- When I restart my computer, I want the computer to use the normal date again (so the environment variable should not be thát persistent :-) ).

### What's the actual problem and how is it linked to this post's title

I already know that setting the environment variable, using `set`, is *not persistent at all* (the variable is not known by the mentioned script).
I also know that setting the environment variable, using Control Panel, is *permanent* (restarting the PC does not remove the variable).

So I'm looking for the "golden midway" (this is a Dutch expression), *I want the variable to be persistent for all programs while the PC is working, but I want it to be removed when I restart the PC*.

Does anybody have an idea?

Comment: Suggested starting points for research: `setx` and a logoff script to reset on reboot.

Comment: `setx` is not the right way to go, as this command write variables to the master environment in the registry (as mentioned by its own help), while I'm looking for some command less persistent.

Comment: How can you tell me it' snot the right way to go, when you are here asking for suggestions on how to do it?  Plus you said yourself "When I restart my computer, I want the computer to use the normal date again"   So set it, then on reboot the logoff script can reset it, seems to match your listed requirement/preference...?   Anyhow.. You're trying to overwrite a system variable, and use it in multiple, disjointed console instances -- it's not going to be smooth.

Comment: How can I unset something which has been set using `setx`? As mentioned in `setx`' help, the command can create or modify an environment variable, but not delete it. So what I can put in my logoff script?

Comment: @Dominique Delete as follows `reg delete HKCU\Environment /F /V _variable`, replace `_variable` with your variable name.

Comment: @DavidPostill: thanks a lot, you saved my day :-) Just one very strange remark: the abbreviation HKCU seems to be known on Windows-10, but the PC I'm working on is Windows-8 and there I must use "HKEY_CURRENT_USER" :-)

Comment: @Dominique `HKCU` should work on any version of Windows